# Make new repo from old commit keeping history up to then

Tags: git

I have a project with some history. Now I want to make a new repo that starts from one specific old commit, say `f0341`. In the new repo I want to keep the linear history up to `f0341` but nothing from after that and no other branches. Can this be achieved?

Comment: This is a great question! If you could, accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the source repository is called `srcrepo` and the destination repository is called `dstrepo`.

Then this should do:

```
cd srcrepo
git checkout f0341
git checkout -b transferbranch

cd ..

git clone --branch transferbranch --single-branch srcrepo dstrepo
cd dstrepo
git checkout transferbranch
git checkout -b master
git branch -d transferbranch
```

Then replace the `origin` remote:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add https://...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an empty repo
Add remote of old repo
Pull the branch, whose HEAD is on f0341
Remove remote of old repo
Add a new remote

(Assuming you don't want to commit into both old and new repos)